# Android extract private and public key from JKS in assets

Tags: java, android, cryptography, key-pair

I have a `JKS` file in `/src/main/res/raw/ecc.jks`. The `EC` algorithm makes the `JKS` file with 256 lengths of key size. My issue is that I want to extract the private and public keys of the `JKS` file and return the new KeyPair. I used the below method but got `java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store`.

```
public KeyPair easyLoadJKS(String alias, String pass) {
    try {
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        InputStream in = _context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ecc);
        keystore.load(in, pass.toCharArray());
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, pass.toCharArray());
        if (!(key instanceof PrivateKey))
            return null;
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
        return new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Keystore Explorer app show the below details:

[image: Algorithem]

[image: Certificate Details]

[image: Private key details]

[image: public key details]

Comment: I would open the key store in https://keystore-explorer.org which will identify the key store type (even if it is a JKS file it doesn't have to be a Java KeyStore File). And then I would recommend to explicitly set the KeyStore type instead of using `KeyStore.getDefaultType()`.

Comment: @Robert I opened with the Keystore Explorer app. It showed that the algorithm is EC and 256. Where I can find the store type?

Comment: Have a look at the status bar at the bottom. It starts `KeyStore Type: ...`.

Comment: @Robert It says the key store type is JKS, I changed the code to `KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")` but the `java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found` fired.